# OpenVPN incomplete RPM?

Tags: openvpn

I'm following [this](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) (official) guide, but I'm stuck at the "*[Setting up your own Certificate Authority (CA) and generating certificates and keys for an OpenVPN server and multiple clients](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki)*" step.

I install (rpm -Uvh..) on a clean CentOS 6 box.
I got the rpm from [their own site](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as-sw/113.html?osfamily=CentOS).

Now, **the problem is**:
I cannot find the `easy-rsa` folder.
I cannot find it in `/usr/share/doc/packages/openvpn` nor `/usr/share/doc/openvpn-2.0`.
No `build-ca` or anything else from this guide.

What can be done?

Comment: Was OpenVPN not in the standard repo?

Comment: try `rpm -l openvp` to find out what files it did install (NB empty directories may have been created by the post-install script rather than being included in the archive)

Answer (score 0):

Download the source tarball, there you'll find the easy-rsa directory, 3 different versions and beyond that (among other scripts) there is the build-ca.

Answer (score 0):

I installed openvpn on a 6.x box, and I see:

```
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/1.0/build-ca
```

This was from `rpm -ql openvpn`

Just to note, this is using "yum install openvpn", which I think pulled the RPM from EPEL (it has Fedora references in the rpm info).  This is not with the package from the OpenVPN site.  I'm not sure how they package that.

Information on EPEL can be found here: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL